# Mahapps Metro Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, user-experience, mahapps.metro

**Background**

I am attempting to build an app in WPF using Mahapps Metro for the very first time. I have followed all of the steps in the Mahapps Quick Start guide [here](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html), yet my results look completely different (shown below):

[image: Mahapps Screwing Up]

I'm not exactly sure what else I should try. My XAML files are exactly the same as the examples.

Here is what my App.xaml file looks like:

```
<Application x:Class="RxExample.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RxExample"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here is what my MainWindow.xaml file looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="RxExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RxExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="368*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="149*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

**Question**

What may be the issue here, or is it Mahapps?

Comment: Can you show us also your MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: @Pikoh absolutely.

Comment: Ok,try changing your `<Window x:Class...` for `<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class..`

Comment: @Pikoh Now I get a compilation error. Partial declarations of 'MainWindow' must not specify different base classes.

Comment: Sure,I forgot to warn you. You have to change it also in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, instead of `MainWindow : Window` it must be `MainWindow : MetroWindow` They have to match

Comment: @Pikoh It's okay, I just needed to change the base class "MainWindow" to "MetroWindow" and now it's okay.

Comment: @Pikoh Right right, thank you! Now... when I run it, things look okay. However, when I am in the layout/editor window it still looks grey/black like in my OP. Why is that?

Comment: It sometimes happens, in fact i don't know why. Maybe closing vs and opening the proyect again... :)

Comment: @Pikoh Put your thoughts down as the answer. Going to finish this up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Also make sure you change in your MainWindow.xaml:

```
Window x:Class... for <Controls:MetroWindow x:Class..`
```

and changing Baseclass in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, instead of `MainWindow : Window` it must be `MainWindow : MetroWindow`

Comment: This is the exact thing they tell you to do in the Quick Start. I have done this.

Comment: @StevieV But the code in your question shows that you derive  `MainWindow` from `Window` instead of `MetroWindow`.

Comment: @ThomasFreudenberg Yep, that is very wrong. One of the users had me fix that, it was either in the comments or in this answer...